# CollectionView not appearing how it is formatted in StoryBoard

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have a collection view to view posts of images. It was working fine before but then I deleted the view controller to try something else and now it won't work correctly.

Right now it is appearing like this:

[image]

Even though I have the Storyboard set up to look like this:

[image]

Any idea why it's doing this?

As requested here is the code:

```
//
//  FeedViewController.swift
//  TheBiggestBlunt
//
//  Created by Nick Steen on 5/16/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Nick Steen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

   //var posts = [Post]()


    var posts1 = [Post]()

    var following = [String]()
    //var posts1 = [String]()
    var userStorage: StorageReference!
    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionview.delegate = self
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        // 1
        fetchPosts()
        // 5
    }

    func fetchPosts() {
        // 2
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        let uids = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        // 3
        uids.observe( DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // 6
            let dict = snapshot.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
            for (_,value) in dict {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String{
                    self.following.append(uid)

                }
            }
            // 7
            ref.observe( DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot2) in
                // 9
                //dictionary of posts
                let dict2 = snapshot2.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
                //go through all the user ids from uids.observe call
                for(key, value) in dict{

                    //for each uid in the following dictionary
                    for uid2 in self.following{
                        //if the posts belong to a user the user is following
                        if (uid2 == key){

                            for (key2,value2) in dict2 {
                                for(key3, value3) in value2 as! [String:NSDictionary]{
                                    let post = Post()
                                   if let author = value3["author"] as? String, let likes = value3["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = value3["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = value3["postID"] as? String, let userID = value3["userID"] as? String{

                                    post.author = author
                                    post.likes = likes
                                    post.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                    post.postID = postID
                                    post.userID = userID
                                    self.posts1.append(post)


                                    print(value3)
                                    }
                                }
                                //print(key2 + "this is key2")

                                    let urlimage = value2
                                    //print(urlimage)
                                    //self.posts1.append(urlimage)

                                    //self.posts1.append(posst)
                                }

                        }
                        }
                    }

                self.collectionview.reloadData()
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                   // 11
//                   self.collectionview.reloadData()
//                }
                // 10
            })

            // 8
        })

        // 4
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) ->Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return posts1.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        //cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts1[indexPath.row]))

        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts1[indexPath.row].pathToImage))
        //creating the cell
        //cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: self.posts[indexPath.row])
//        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
//
//


        //let stickitinme = URL(fileURLWithPath: posts1[0])
        //cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: stickitinme)

        //cell.authorLabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].author
        //cell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes) Likes"

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func signOutPressed(_sender: Any){
           signOut()
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignIn", sender: nil)
       }

    @objc func signOut(){
           KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey:"uid")

           do{
               try Auth.auth().signOut()
           } catch let signOutError as NSError{
               print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
           }
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

//        let spaceRef = userStorage(forURL: posts1[0])
//         // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
//         spaceRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
//           // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
//           let pic = UIImage(data: data)
//           picArray.append(pic)
//        })



    //        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    //            // Get download URL from snapshot
    //            print(snapshot.value)
    //
    //            // Create a storage reference from the URL
    //
    //            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://thebiggestblunt-f3f10.appspot.com")
    //                        for data in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary{
    //
    //                            print("data is:", data)
    ////                            for uid85 in self.following{
    ////
    ////
    ////                            }
    //                          storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024){data,error in
    //                              if let error = error {
    //                                    print(error)
    //                               } else {
    //                                    //print(self.imageCount)
    //                                   let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
    //                                  self.posts.append(pic!)
    //
    //
    //                                   self.collectionview.reloadData()
    //                                   print(self.photoArray)
    //
    //                                }
    //                            }
    //                        }
    //                    })
    //
    //
    //
    //        })
    //
    //
    //        let size = posts.count
    //        print(size)

//    func fetchPosts(){
//
//       let storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://thebiggestblunt-f3f10.appspot.com")
//
//        userStorage = storage.child("users")
//        let ref = Database.database().reference()
//
//        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
//
//        //get all userIDs
//        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
//        if let users = snapshot.value as? [String : NSDictionary]{
//            //for each userID in users
//            for (_,value) in users {
//                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String{
                    // finds the current user
//                    if uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                            // extracts all users that this user is following
//                        if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String: String]{
//                            for(_, user) in followingUsers {
//                                self.following.append(user)
//                            }
//                           //append yourself to the list of following self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
//                        }
//                        self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
//
//


    // get all of the posts
    //ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

                        // gets all of the posts into a dictionary
//
//                            let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : NSDictionary]

    //                          looks at the value in all of the posts
//
//                            for(_, post) in postsSnap {
                                    // get the user id of the post
//                                if let userID = post["userID"] as? String{


//                                    for each in self.following{
                                        // if the user is in the following list then add it to the feed
//                                        if each == userID{
//                                            let posst = Post()
//                                            if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String{
//
//                                                posst.author = author
//                                                posst.likes = likes
//                                                posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
//                                                posst.postID = postID
//                                                posst.userID = userID
//
//                                                self.posts.append(posst)
//                                            }
//                                        }
//                                    }
//                                    self.collectionview.reloadData()
//                                }
//                            }
//                        })
//                    }
//                }
//            }}
//
//        })
//
//         ref.removeAllObservers()
//    }
```

Comment: If you are subclassing a UICollectionViewController and did set  the presenting view controller as its delegate the subclassed controller methods that you might have implemented won't be called.

Comment: what are the subclassed controller methods? I am subclassing, but this was working before and now it's not. Do you have any information on why the storyboard would ignore my configuration? the number of sections is set to 1 so there shouldn't be 7 sections in a line.

Comment: If you dont post your code (UICollectionView controller), how you present it and how you set its delegate I can only guess what's going on. if it is not getting called as I said don't set the presenting view controller as its

Comment: again make sure that method where you set the sections to 1 it is getting called

Comment: I updated the code. I tried messing with constraints and now it doesn't work at all. please help :(((